# Select Range of SQLDateTimes

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, date-range, sqldatetime

```
table = {{ID1, SQLDateTime[{1978, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.`}]}, 
{ID2, SQLDateTime[{1999, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.`}]}, 
{ID3, SQLDateTime[{2010, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0.`}]}, 
{ID4, SQLDateTime[{2011, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.`}]}}
```

I'd like to return all cases in `table` in which the SQLDateTime is within the last year (`DatePlus[{-1, "Year"}]`). How do I specify a search for those cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select[table, (AbsoluteTime[ DatePlus[{-1, "Year"}]] <= 
    AbsoluteTime[ #[[2, 1]]] <= AbsoluteTime[ ] &)]

(* ==> {{ID3, SQLDateTime[{2010, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0.}]}, 
        {ID4,SQLDateTime[{2011, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}]}
        } 
*)
```

---

Small update (pre-caching of Date[], based on Leonid's comments):

```
With[
 {date = Date[]},
 Select[table, 
    (AbsoluteTime[ DatePlus[date, {-1, "Year"}]] <= 
     AbsoluteTime[ #[[2, 1]]] <= AbsoluteTime[date ] &)]
 ]
```

This also removes a problem with the original `DatePlus[{-1, "Year"}]` which only takes today's *date* into account and not the current *time*.

Comment: @Leonid ;-D  A toast on future dates

Comment: @Sjoerd  Yeah, I'll drink to that :)

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `DateDifference`:

```
Cases[table, {a_, SQLDateTime[b_]} /; 
  DateDifference[b, DateList[], "Year"][[1]] <= 1]
```